# What is needed to insert an image into oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We are planning to develop a simple image viewer using oracle and VB.How do we insert an image into an oracle database table?What is required to insert an image into the oracle table?Please provide the query and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Intermedia is Oracle's own solution to storing images in
the database.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/intermedia-rel-quickstart-083139.html
and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14302/ch_intr.htm

You can also store images in
the database independent of Oracle Intermedia
using the `BLOB` column type, if you prefer to avoid Oracle database extensions.